# How can I exclude watched resources from the automatic publishing in eclipse embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I am working on a GWT project in eclipse, using an embedded Tomcat server with auto publishing 'on'.

Some of the maintained java sources are subject to the GWT compiler (which produces javascript for the client side) and not part of the server side code. Nevertheless, changing such client side sources triggers the auto publish to tomcat server (i.e. Tomcat restarts the application), which takes about 30 seconds. Which is really annoying because these files are never deployed to the server side.

How can I exclude these resources from beeing watched by the auto publisher?

Versions:

- eclipse: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
- GWT: 2.8.1
- Tomcat: 8.0

Answer (score 0):

In the build area (".../target/project-name/" if using maven), you want just the "server" code compiled to the `WEB-INF` directory, because like all servlet containters tomcat looks for server code in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Sry, I do not understand what you mean by "build area".

Comment: By build area I mean the folder where the compiled source code (*.class) is put, as well as other resources that are needed at runtime (HTML/CSS files, web.xml, etc)

Comment: And now? what to do to exclude some packages from beeing watched by the auto publisher?

Comment: are you using maven and the gwt-maven plugin?

Comment: what is produced by the final build of the project?  You get a jar file.  Is the client-side html/javascript bundled in the jar, or separate?

Comment: Yes and yes (maven & gwt-maven-plugin). There are four maven sub-modules, where only one of them is a gwt project. Other three produce a jar, which are dependencies of the gwt module projekt. Latter produces a war.

Comment: with the gwt-maven-plugin, by default, only code in src/main/java/myproj/server/ (package myproj.server) and src/main/java/myproj/shared/ (package myproj.shared) end up in target/myproj/WEB-INF/classes/ .  And when you run tomcat during testing, it should only be looking for class file changes in the WEB-INF/classes .   SO, look in there and see if GWT code is appearing in there too.  By convention, the GWT client code lives in src/main/myproj/client/ (myproj.client package), and does not appear in WEB-INF/classes/